# Can I use the Corona SDK to make iPhone apps and sell them via the app store in a windows environment?

Tags: iphone, windows, app-store, coronasdk

I know that I can install Corona in a windows machine (as I just did), but will it be possible to sell the app I'm going to make at the app store? Moreover, if Corona is just for Mac, can I install a virtual machine on my PC so I can fake a Mac environment to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CoronaSDK works for iPhone development on Windows and you can sell apps on the appstore without a mac.  All you need is an iOS developer account and Corona.  Corona will compile your application in the cloud, you don't need a mac or Xcode like you would using other iPhone dev tools.

Comment: You do need a Mac to compile the app for iOS, even though you can build the app on windows testing it either on android or in the corona simulator

Answer (score 1):

No, you must have a Mac to build for iOS.

Per the Corona Website:

"The Corona SDK on Windows only supports building for Android."

"The Corona SDK on Mac supports building for both iOS and Android."

[See Corona's Website](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/getting-started-corona-game-edition)